# Why is the word "existed" correct in “it never existed”?

Tags: word-usage

I'm writing lyrics for my song, and hit upon the passage "Don't tell me that it never exist."
But I asked my English teacher for correction, then he told me that "exist" should be replaced with "existed."

I can't completely understand the reason why. It maybe because the word "never" used with, I guess. Am I right? Or are there any other reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons.

First, "it never exist" is never grammatical: you mean "it never exists".

The second is much more subtle. "Don't tell me it never exists" is grammatical, but is not something an English speaker is likely to say.

I am struggling to explain why this is, but I think the answer is something like this:

"This exists" is not usually a property that can come and go: a thing either exists (or doesn't) for all time, (qualities, for example), or comes into existence at some time, and continues to exist until it no longer does (people, for example).

To negate that, we usually say "doesn't exist". "Never exists" sounds odd, and to me it would imply that we are talking about some odd kind of thing that sometimes exists and sometimes doesn't, and we are saying that this particular thing never does.

An example (somewhat contrived): The King (of a particular country) is something that can exist at some times but not at others. So at present there is a King of Spain, but no King of the United Kingdom.

In that context, I can imagine somebody saying "The King of Spain exists, the King of the UK doesn't exist, and the King of the United States never exists". (It's not a likely thing to say, but it makes sense, sort of).

With a past tense, "never" is slightly different. To say something "never existed" is not unusual - it means that it doesn't exist now, and never has; but it does not have that implication of something that might come and go.

So in summary: "Don't tell me that it never exist**s**" would be grammatical, but unusual, and would imply that "it" was in principle something that could exist and not exist at different times. "Don't tell me that it never exist**ed**" would be normal, and not imply that the thing could come and go.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear answer, sir! About the first reason, I just carelessly mistook, but didn't know a lot about second reason.

Comment: There are some situations where one would say *never exists*.  For example, "A situation where no one says *never exists, never exists.*"  The meaning can be distilled down to *without consideration of the past, this situation will never exist in the present.*  Which implies it would also not exist in the past.

Answer (score 1):

"Exist" is present tense. If you say, "It doesn't exist", you mean that it doesn't exist right now.

That says nothing about the past. It would be quite reasonable to say, "The Roman Empire does not exist." It doesn't exist today. But it did exist in the past.

If you combine "exist" with the word "never", you can't just be talking about the present. You're saying that not only does it not exist now, but that it did not exist at any time in the past. So you must use the past tense, "It never existed."

Side note: One could argue that logically, it should use a past continuous and write, "It never was existing." But we just don't do that. We use the simple past.

Answer (score 0):

But you might also say that "the King of the UK used to exist" but it's not a great use of the word.

I think for the OP it is like this.

Dinosaurs existed 66 million years ago
There exists a theory of evolution introduced by Charles Darwin
As far as we can prove no God exists which is almost the same as saying no God has ever existed
Bitcoin is a virtual currency that exists only in cyber-space

So you can see that the word changes based on whether you are dealing with the past or present tense.

Hope that helps.